# Problem with oplus symbol in newtxmath

Tags: rendering, newtxmath

I'm a new LaTeX user(overleaf and miktex) and I like to use the newtxmath package for my notes. I noticed that the oplus symbol looks with deformation ONLY in adobe reader for PC (in other viewers looks fine), so I want to know if this problem is just mine or if it's a general problem.

Here's my code(I compile with pdflatex):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
 $\oplus$
\end{document}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to provide a minimally compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that generates the problem behavior (under Adobe Reader) you wish to fix.

Comment: My test with MiKTeX and Adobe Reader DC works fine (both are recent version). Symbol hasn't any deformations.